# Making an HTTP Request in HTML Form Resolution

Tags: php, html, forms, http, openfire

I'm trying to make a registration page for an Openfire XMPP server.  The easiest route seems to be to use the [user service plugin](http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/userservice/readme.html) to register accounts, which lets you register users with HTTP requests.

Essentially, I need to make HTTP requests like

```
http://hostname:9090/plugins/userService/userservice?type=add&secret=passcode&username=kafka&password=drowssap&name=franz&email=franz@kafka.com
```

Which will register user `kafka` with password `drowssap`, name `franz`, etc.

So it seems to me the best method would be to create an HTML form which collects the user information, then makes the HTTP request.  This seems simple enough, but I'm not sure where the best place to start is. PHP? Python? Wget? Lynx? I'm not quite sure how to use those from within an HTML form.

Thanks.

Comment: Use whatever programming language you feel most comfortable with. The form submits to your script, then it can call the API.

Comment: What languages (backend) do you know? If it's PHP you could just `file_get_contents` on `hostname:9090` with user input from `$_POST`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't EVER include sensible data that way. That's a GET request. You need a POST request (which doesn't include data in the URL).

Your HTML should be like:

```
<form action="saveData.php" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" />
    <input type="password" name="password" />
    <!-- other inputs here -->
    <input type="submit" value="Create user" />
</form>
```

That form sends POST data to the saveData.php script. That script should process the parameters and redirect to another page.

```
<?php
    // Here process the data the way you want (using data inside $_POST array, i.e. $_POST['username'], $_POST['password'], etc...
    // Usually you'd want to save to a database
   // When done, redirect to "success" page
   header("Location: success.php");
?>
```

Your success.php page can contain anything:

```
<?php
    echo "User created successfully!";
?>
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about what the saveData.php script should contain?

Comment: That'd be too long for this purpose (helping you, not doing your work) and it would depend on what do you need to do. You should read a PHP tutorial (or ASP tutorial, or whatever language you'd like to use) and then you will get your answer.